# Changing the label for the module when registering on Django admin

Tags: python, django, model, label, admin

I have a package (Django app) named **book_author_publisher_category**. This name is just to clarify, because I have these four models inside this app for they have some constraints.

Is there a way of changing the label of the section containing these models that I registered on my admin?

My **book_author_publisher_category/admin.py** file is like:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from book_author_publisher_category.models import *

# Registering the models on admin site
admin.site.register([Publisher, Author, Category, Book])
```

The section with the models I've registered on admin are named as the app name. How can I custom that?

[image: How my admin site looks like now]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change the [verbose name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/applications/#for-application-authors) of an app:

**book_author_publisher_category/apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class BAPCConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'book_author_publisher_category'
    verbose_name = "Book's data"
```

**book_author_publisher_category/__init__.py**

```
default_app_config = 'book_author_publisher_category.apps.BAPCConfig'
```

Comment: In this case, I'd like to register all the four models as a list as mentioned before, but with a name "Book's data". Is that possible?

Comment: Right answer, thanks. Can you show me where these instructions are placed on the documentation?

Comment: I provided this link in the answer:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/applications/#for-application-authors  Excerpt: _here’s how you would provide a proper name for the admin_

Comment: @cataravan didn't realize that, sorry.